# Restoring previous purchases in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to restore the previous purchases when my app is logged from another device. I use the following code, but the issue is that the restore is never completed. It throws an error

> Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    //newly added code to restore function
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Should I wait for the app to finish the restore or is this an error? But nothing happens.

Comment: This function trigerred by a UI action? Like a button tap, or you call this function when the user logged in?

Comment: That code doesn’t look right. It looks like the function that is invoked by your transaction observer to handle the restoration of a purchase; it should use the supplied transaction to provide the purchased item

Comment: Also is this your entire code for purchase restoration?please share your complete code

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Following is the code flow.

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
 self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];


 }

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: 
     (SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 {
     purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", 
     queue.transactions.count);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
  {
  NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
 // [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
// NSLog(@"Product id in buyproduct:%@",productID);
 }
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult 
resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK    messageAsString:@"1"];
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result 
callbackId:self.callbackId];
 }
```